# How to get POST request to work with GWAN using JAVA servlets

Tags: java, servlets, post, g-wan

I'm experimenting with java servlets using GWAN. It's easy to get GET requests to work using the api.Gwan class.

My problem is how do I get POST requests to work.

```
import api.Gwan;

public class ProccessGETRequest {
    public static int jmain(long env, String[] args) {
    //GET request  is contained in the args
    ...
    //but how do you access the POST request?
    }
}
```

If this functionality does not exist, could someone suggest an implementation.
This would be easier to figure out if the api.Gwan class were open source... :(

Answer (score 0):

In C servlets both post and get args is in "args". I haven't tried java in G-WAN but i think the post args should be on the same location.

Answer (score 0):

Richard is right: G-WAN does the parsing for you so `jmain(args)` contain the arguments of both GET and POST requests.

There's nothing special to do on your end, see the `loan.java` example which can be used in both modes, GET and POST.

For some languages the G-WAN API is sometimes ported partially (like for C# or Java) because it makes little sense to use G-WAN `xbuffers` which are playing with UTF8 on platforms that use UTF16 characters and abstracted `strings` (they require a data copy anyway to talk to G-WAN).

The same goes with high-performance routines which would lost their purpose (speed) if they were encapsulated in language wrappers.

But if you are missing something specific then the G-WAN developers are open to adding features, as I have seen in the past. Just drop them a line.